# How can couchbase be used as a caching layer on top of oracle?

Tags: oracle, memcached, couchbase

I have Oracle as my main RDBMS for read and write, but I want to use couchbase as caching layer as it has map-reduce as can be used as memcache. Any idea as to how i can implement that, and how to transfer and update data in the caching layer, when Oracle is updated or inserted etc.

Comment: What does map-reduce have to do with caching?

Comment: nothing to do with caching ... But I can use it on the data stored in the caching layer to run queries faster and perform some nice reduce functions.

Comment: If you can keep it all in memory (that's the point of caching, right?) map-reduce seems like the wrong paradigm.

Comment: Don`t worry abt the map reduce part .. that`s how views are implemented in couchbase ... can u help me with the quesn. http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing.html

Comment: Couldn't you go with a messaging based architecture and decouple your different app domains? I'm not familiar with Oracle and direct interaction with e.g RabbitMQ, etc. but you could take care of this in your applications and use a pub/sub architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling anything about your current performance issues.

I have seen too many applications which do not really take advantage of RDBMS/SQL features, especially if an ORM sits in between.

The cure is to put *another* cache on top of a database, and to synchronize this in a cluster manually using IP multicasts (SwarmCache for example), message queues (JMS) or nightly import jobs. It could create more problems in the end. And it increases system complexity.

So my answer to your question is: I would not do it, as long as there is room for improvement regarding your data model and/or queries.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is about Database synchronization. This can be done through a combination of using DB dependencies and "right-thru" features that I am not too sure about whether couchbase offers. So with DB dependency you have cached items dependent upon Db items and if the DB items are updated or deleted the corresponding dependent item in the cache is removed and at the same time you can write a "right-thru" handler executed at the server level; and the main purpose of this handler is loading fresh copies of the removed items in the cache. So, basically, you'll write the handler once and registerit with the cache server and the cache server will execute it when needed to sync. new items in the DB with the cache. [This reading on Db synchronization can be useful](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/database-synchronization.html) . Its based on a product Ncache.

Comment: I am trying to use Apache kafka which uses a producer consumer model ... in which producer will take data from oracle and consumer will consume data in couchbase which will get updated ... smthng like that

Answer (score 1):

So your question is not directly related to Couchbase, but as other stated more about how you can be alerted when data are changing into your Oracle instance.

One thing that is not well known is the Oracle Database Change Notification feature that is quite cool for this:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm

So you can create an application that is listening to your changes and pushes the data into Couchbase.